# Will Elesh Norn kill creatures if I don't pay the extra cost for Flash?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I use [Flash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=16440) to bring [Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elesh%20Norn%2C%20Grand%20Cenobite) into play, then choose to sacrifice her rather than pay her mana cost. Will my opponent's creatures with two or less toughness die?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, Elesh Norn's static abilities have no effect on the battlefield in that case.**

Bringing Elesh Norn into play with Flash and deciding whether or not to sacrifice it is all part of Flash's resolution. Killing creatures with her -2/-2 would require state-based effects to be checked, but that only happens after Flash has finished resolving, at which point Eles Norn is already gone.

If you sacrifice a creature brought into play with the spell Flash, basically all you get are "enters the battlefield" and "leaves the battlefield" effects.

Answer (score 8):

No, since no player receives priority between [Elesh Norn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elesh%20Norn) entering and leaving the battlefield during the resolution of [Flash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flash). State-based actions that would place creatures with 0 toughness in their owners graveyards, are not checked until just before a player would receive priority. Rule 704.4 gives a nice example of a creature that has 0 toughness temporarily, that isn't sent to the graveyard, because its toughness is greater than 0 the next time it would be checked.

> 116.5. Each time a player would get priority, the game first performs all applicable state-based actions as a single event (see rule 704, “State-Based Actions”), ...

> 704.4. Unlike triggered abilities, state-based actions pay no attention to what happens during the resolution of a spell or ability.

> **Example:** A player controls a creature with the ability “This creature’s power and
> toughness are each equal to the number of cards in your hand” and casts a spell whose
> effect is “Discard your hand, then draw seven cards.” **The creature will temporarily have
> toughness 0 in the middle of the spell’s resolution but will be back up to toughness 7 when
> the spell finishes resolving. Thus the creature will survive when state-based actions are
> checked.** In contrast, an ability that triggers when the player has no cards in hand goes on
> the stack after the spell resolves, because its trigger event happened during resolution.

> 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.